# What is the behavior of async method called from sync context for the code snippet shown?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, azure-eventhub

In following code snippet, I am accessing async method in sync context. The parent thread is running in thread pool.

```
public async Task AsyncWriteToEventHub(Data data, string correlationId) 
{
    await this.eventHubClinet.SendBatchAsync(data);
}
 
public void WriteData(Data data) 
{
    AsyncWriteToEventHub(Data);
}
```

Surprisingly, I am not getting any compilation error while calling `AsyncWriteToEventHub()` event though I am not using `await()` or `wait()` in `WriteData`.

Questions:

1. Will there be a deadlock since I am running these functions in thread pool?
2. Does `AsyncWriteToEventHub` will run on separate thread? If Yes, I am not waiting on the thread object?
3. What will happen to child thread when parent completes the execution? `AsyncWriteToEventHub` is a fire-and-forget method for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will there be a deadlock since I am running these functions in thread pool?

There is no deadlock. Your code is not blocking on asynchronous code, so the [classic deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (as described on my blog) will not occur.

> Does AsyncWriteToEventHub will run on separate thread?

No. Why would it?

> If Yes, I am not waiting on the thread object? What will happen when parent completes the execution?

Your code is not (a)waiting for the method to complete. So your code never knows when the method completes. So your code cannot know when it is safe for the application to exit, and it cannot even be aware of exceptions thrown by the asynchronous method.

Usually, this is not desirable. It's more natural to `await` every task sooner or later.

Comment: AsyncWriteToEventHub method is fire and forget for me. I do not worry about exception thrown by this method.

will AsyncWriteToEventHub return task object?
Do I need to worry about handling it gracefully since parent might complete before child?
What happens to child task when parent completes it's execution?

Comment: There is no parent or child here because as you said it is fire and forget. `AsyncWriteToEventHub` will return a task which is ignored ("forgotten").

Comment: Will AsyncWriteToEventHub continue to run and complete it, even though WriteData completes the execution before AsyncWriteToEventHub ?

Comment: Also, will it cause problem when AsyncWriteToEventHub  will try to look for context to continue the execution, but WriteData is already completed.

Comment: `WriteData` isn't providing the context, so that's no problem. `AsyncWriteToEventHub` will continue executing just like normal.